# Excel: Value and date in same cell

Tags: excel, vba, date

the question is: is there a way to store a value, eg. string "CODE1", and a date in the same cell?

example: A1.value="CODE1" and A1.date=01/01/2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to put the two value visible in the cell, you can use:

```
Range("A1").Value = "CODE1 " & Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

if you need to add an Hidden second value, you can use the ID:

```
Range("A1").Value = "CODE1"
Range("A1").ID = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")

MsgBox Range("A1").Value
MsgBox Range("A1").ID
```

Comment: awesome answer, just one more thing: what type of data can i store in .ID? i know i should be working with arrays with x,y,z axis for this kind of thing but im limited to x,y axis and i need 2 independent values for each (x,y)---- would this work for excel 2010? thanks

Comment: In the ID you can add number or string, but only one value. If for you it's ok, you can *built* a string with the two/three value: **x & "-" & y & "-" & z**, After you can use with **xyzArray = Split(.ID,"-")**. Obviusly you cannot add 1 million of char in the ID...

Comment: awesome, thanks, you just saved me a lot a headaches and time